# Python debugger in Emacs: set keybindings similar to perldb?

Tags: python, perl, debugging, emacs

I am starting to use the `pdb` Python debugger in Emacs, and I am used to the keys in the perl debugger, which I would like to also be able to use in `pdb`. How can I configure the debugger in Emacs to have the same keybindings as in Perl, like "restart=R" or "print=x"?

I don't mind if this is only specific to debugging in Emacs and not the pdb debugger in the console, I am going to do all my debugging in Emacs anyway.

Comment: You could add your request here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1248657 However not sure if it's affordable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code I use to do force a pdb restart, which first sends a restart via comint-send-input, but falls back to killing and restarting the pdb process with the same arguments and default-directory if that fails.

```
(defun pdb-restart ()
  (interactive)
  (comint-insert-send "restart")
  (sleep-for .5)
  (when
      (or
       (last-lines-match "raise Restart.*
    Restart")
       (last-lines-match "restart")
       (not (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))))
    (let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil );disable confirming for process kill
          (pdbcmd (car-safe (symbol-value (gud-symbol 'history nil 'pdb))))
          (default-directory default-directory))
      (kill-this-buffer)
      (cd default-directory)
      (pdb pdbcmd)))
  (comint-insert-send "n"))

(defun comint-insert-send (input)
  (insert input)
  (comint-send-input))

(defun last-lines-match (regexp &optional n)
  (unless n (setf n 3))
  (re-search-backward regexp (line-beginning-position (- 0 n)) t))
```

You can bind pdb-restart to 'R' via something like this:

```
(add-hook 'pdb-mode-hook '(define-key (current-local-map) "R" 'pdb-restart))
```

As for print, in pdb, you can simply do `p pythonexpression`, so there isn't much to short-cut. However, you can bind x to 'print ' using the following:

```
(define-key gud-mode-map "x" (lambda () (interactive)  (insert "print ")))
```